# Web Hook Activity In Azure Data Factory to Real Time Data Integration to SQL from an App End point

Tags: webhooks, azure-synapse, oracle-adf

I have been looking to get real time integration of data from an app end point to Azure SQL using ADF webhook? If there is any updates in the application data it needs to be pulled using ADF webhook and update the SQL table? How can I achieve this? Is there any method to trigger the pipeline to execute the moment a data change happens in the source application?

Regards,
Sandeep